Add a python package to a PySide6 QtCreator project by .whl file
I have a custom python package that I created it is stored inside a .whl file and I would like to use it in my PySide6 QtCreator project; this package is only useful to me and I don't want to gum up PyPi with things that nobody else will ever use. I would like use this package in my project, but I don't know how to include my package in the project, or even install the package to the venv. My project will depend on the package, and I would also like it to be distributed with the qt project whenever I share the code with anyone else. What is the recommended/default way to do this or is there even a recommended way to do this in the first place?
Update: is it possible to commit the whl file to the repository and then include it in the requirements file? If so it will work decently well with QtCreator.

Why do you need to install it separately as a wheel? Why not just symlink the package in your pyside project and add a copy to the distribution?

I will likely be wanting to distribute exe files to other people with this software, and this package will likely be used in other projects I work on in the future. I could do it, and I'm not opposed to that, but if it's possible I would like to keep their code bases separate completely and make one a dependency of the other in a more "pythonic" way. QtCreator is also very specific about what code does appear as part of your project and what does not, if I did that none of that code would appear in QtCreator without a fight; another reason why I would prefer to use a supported method.

I looked into it, and it turns out that I can commit my .whl file to the repository, and then add it to the requirements.txt file. After this I click the Build button

and the .whl file will automatically be installed and used in the pyside project from now on. The .whl file doesn't appear in the file browser for QtCreator, but if I use the terminal, I can add it to the repo. I can't install it using pip in the terminal, because the terminal can't access the venv, that is why I have to use the build button.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
